# .append to "Add This Event" widget summary text using jQuery (Syntax Help)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-append

I am unable to append values into the `_summary` class or any other. I believe its a really simple syntax error I am making. I have been trying different syntax's for the past day, with no luck.

I am using [this](http://addthisevent.com/) widget.

Please help.

#### jQuery

```
$("._summary").append("hello world");
```

#### HTML

```
<a href="http://example.com/link-to-your-event" title="Add to Calendar" class="addthisevent" id="addthisevent">
    Add to Calendar
    <span class="_start">10-05-2014 11:38:46</span>
    <span class="_end">11-05-2014 11:38:46</span>
    <span class="_zonecode">1</span>
    <span class="_summary">Summary of the event</span>
    <span class="_description">Description of the event</span>
    <span class="_location">Location of the event</span>
    <span class="_organizer">Organizer</span>
    <span class="_organizer_email">Organizer e-mail</span>
    <span class="_all_day_event">false</span>
    <span class="_date_format">DD/MM/YYYY</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure you included jQuery? Are you sure the document is ready before trying to do it?

Comment: Are these being added after the page is loaded? Check your console, that element may not exist when you're trying to run that command.

Comment: Works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/Kb6Dj/.

Comment: Try wrapping that in a timeout temporary to see if that works, the element probably isn't there when you're trying to append to it.

Comment: did you try it under firebug or similar tool? are there error messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After that calendar widget code does it's magic, all those internal `<span>` elements are set to `display: none`. The code is probably working, as you could verify with your browser developer tools (inspect the DOM).

After your code that modifies the text, add this:

```
addthisevent.refresh();
```

It's there in the FAQ. [Here is a fork of VisioN's fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/h478R/)

Answer (score 2):

The text is being appended just fine. After you bind the AddThisEvent widget to the parent element, the child span elements are being hidden.

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/782fa/)**</kbd>

```
<span class="_summary" style="display: none;">
    Summary of the event
    hello world
</span>
```

To make sure your updates to the `<span>` elements carry over to the calendar event, you can update your element with jQuery before calling the AddThisEvent Widget like this.

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/782fa/)**</kbd>

```
<script>
    $("._summary").append("hello world");
</script>

<!-- AddThisEvent -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.addthisevent.com/atemay.js"></script>
```

If that's not possible, it looks like you can also call the `addthisevent.refresh();` method to refresh the data.

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/782fa/4/)**</kbd>

```
<!-- AddThisEvent -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.addthisevent.com/atemay.js"></script>

<script>
    $("._summary").append("hello world");
    addthisevent.refresh();
</script>
```

Comment: ok, the text is being appended perfectly but it isn't being added to the .ics Calendar event, when I download it. Any idea how to add it?

Comment: Updated my answer. Is it possible to make your jQuery calls to the `span` elements before embedding the AddThisEvent widget?